# Exclude key in "keydown" function

Tags: javascript

So I want to exclude the escape key from my key down code because i have another "keydown" function that closes the nav by pressing escape.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', openNav);
```

and this is the close code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
     if(e.keyCode === 27) {
        closeNav();
    }
});
```

so basically I want to be able to close the nav using escape and be able to use any other key to open the navigation

Comment: `if (e.keyCode !== 27) openNav()`?

Comment: You should just have a single keydown function and check for the specific keys in there and perform whatever appropriate action.

Comment: That empty function followed by an `else if` statement doesn't look like a valid Javascript syntax.

Comment: @goodvibration yeh i cropped another code out of it and left it else if i fixed it though

Comment: It's great that you figured it out, but the question needs to remain a question. Otherwise, people visiting later only get half the conversation. You can post your own answer separately. [We encourage it!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I will fix this up tomorrow thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help everyone I found the answer here is what I did to fix my problem:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
//27 = escape
    if(e.keyCode === 27) {
        closeNav();
    } else if(e.keyCode !== 27) {
        openNav();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, I used `if` and `else if`

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 27) {
        closeNav();
    } else if(e.keyCode === 32) {//key space
        openNav();
    }
});
```

Comment: are you sure "any" is a valid numerical value it does not seem to work for me

Comment: @anormalmouse revise this page the codes ascii https://theasciicode.com.ar/

Comment: I have read that already before im confused what you mean about the "any" are you trying to say put any code instead of "any" or is "any" is supposed to be a numerical value instead of say "32"

Comment: OK I get where you where going but this does not correctly answer my question sorry i am looking for if any key(accept esc)  is pressed it will open the navigation and when esc is pressed it will close nav thanks for helping but I already found a answer anyways